# How can I join tables on a substring in a record?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table that associates names with account ID's, like this

```
**Accounts**
name
account_id
```

and another table like that assocates information with account uri's

```
**Info**
information
account_uri
```

An account uri looks like this: /some/random/path/123456/randomDigits

Where 123456 is the accound_id associated with the user.

How can I join these tables, and get a result like

```
**results**
name
information
```

It's an amazon redshift/postgresql database. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Are all your ids in account_uri 6 figures?

Comment: Anywhere between 5 and 7 digits

Comment: @johncorser i believe what Mihai is trying to get at is that if the ID matches the uri number.

Comment: Yes, the account_id matches the uri number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work if you aren't able to put the `account_id` in the Info table:

```
SELECT A.Name,
  I.Information
FROM Information I
JOIN Account A
  ON A.account_id = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([account_uri]),0,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(account_uri))))
```

The `REVERSE(...)` is being used to create a LastIndexOf function.

Might want to just do:

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([account_uri]),0,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(account_uri))))
FROM Information
```

To see if the SUBSTRING/REVERSE are getting the entire account id

This should find the second string between '/'

```
SUBSTRING(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([account_uri]),CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(account_uri)))),0,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([account_uri]),CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(account_uri)))))
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm getting a null set. It's probably something to do with the tables themselves, so I'll try to work that out and I'll mark this accepted as soon as I know for sure it works.

Comment: ok, i'd do (add)the select of the `REVERSE` on the information table to make sure the result is getting the correct value

Comment: Ah, the problem is the format of the account_uri is actually /path/to/123456/randomNumbers where 123456 is the account_uri. I will revise the question. Do you have any idea how to join on that by any chance?

Comment: ugly is OK if it gets the data merged!

Comment: will post, you'll have to massage it i'm sure, but basically I'm going to REVERSE it, find the first '/' and then look for the first '/' after that...

Comment: It still returns an empty set

Comment: When I run `select  SUBSTRING(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([account_uri]),CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(account_uri)))),0,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([account_uri]),CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(account_uri)))))) from exp_logs limit 15` I only get empty cells

Comment: what if you change the `0` to `1`?

Comment: When I change the `0` to a `1`, all of the records appear as `/`

Comment: well.. you'll have to play with it... i don't have an easy way to mock it

Comment: Thanks for your help. When/if I figure it out I'll post here.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be efficient, but you can do:

```
select a.name, i.information
from accounts a join
     info i
     on i.account_uri like '%/' || a.account_id;
```

Unfortunately, with this data structure it is hard to take advantage of indexes.

Comment: It does work, but it takes a very long time and my data set will only be getting larger.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution

```
SELECT a.name, i.information
FROM accounts AS a
INNER JOIN info AS i ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(i.account_url, '/', -1) = a.account_id
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cb08/2)

Side note: This isn't a proper structure at all ;) And I'm not sure if this works on PostgreSQL because of SUBSTRING_INDEX function. I really didn't notice that this is related to PostgreSQL.